# What is this old 50mm f/1.9 lens?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, old-lenses, equipment-identification

I purchased this lens for $5 at a thrift store. It's fully functional and the glass seems in good condition, however, I cannot identify the mount or the lens (the front name ring is missing).

When I searched F=1.9 and 50mm, all I found online was a Chinon lens with a Pentax K mount. This is **not** a K mount, as I cannot mount it on my Pentax bodies and adapters. I couldn't mount it on Canon A-1 or on Minolta MD mount either.

### What is this lens?

[image: back]

[image: front - missing ring]
[image: back]

[image: side]
[image: side]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your lens is a [Yashica ML 50mm f/1.9](http://allphotolenses.com/lenses/item/c_370.html#prettyPhoto). The one pictured below is a more recent version of the same lens.

The mount is the CONTAX/Yashica mount. Yashica revived the Contax name over a decade after production of any Contax rangefinder cameras and lenses in Germany had ended. Yashica chose to officially market the line as 'CONTAX' (always in all capital letters).

The C/Y mount, newly designed by Zeiss for Yashica in 1975, has a registration (flange focal) distance of 45.5mm. This means it is fairly easily adaptable for use on modern cameras with a shorter registration distance, such as the Canon EF, Minolta/Sony A-mount, Sigma SA, Canon FL/FD, Four-Thirds, M39, Leica M, and most all popular mirrorless camera mounts (µ4/3, Sony E, Fuji X, EF-M, Nikon 1, etc).

[image]